# Sidewall repeatedly splitting in same place on rim

Tags: tire, repair, innertube, rims, puncture

Good afternoon, folks. Wondering if anyone has had this or a similar issue:

I blew a tire a few weeks back and replaced the tube and tire after thoroughly inspecting the rim for damage. After a few rides the air in my tire let go while sitting in my living room. The sidewall had spread open and I assumed it was faulty rubber. I've since replaced the tire twice and each time, after a few rides, the sidewall splits at the same place on the rim. I've inspected the rim and there seems to be no visible damage but it's starting to get expensive to troubleshoot. Below is a picture of similar damage to illustrate (not my tire but same result)

Thanks for any input!

[image]

Comment: Check to make sure that your brakes aren't rubbing on the tire.

Comment: No rubbing from brakes, my last trip out the tire blew within half a mile of riding. Could the tire needing to be trued play a role?

Comment: Inspect the rim for a sharp edge on the hook that holds the bead. Also make sure that they are not over-inflated. If it was twice the same brand of tyre it could point to poor quality, switch the brand.

Comment: same brand/model of tire?

Comment: I think you need to check your brakes again.

Comment: If your wheel is out of round, the brakes may be an issue at only one point on the rim.

Comment: Note that a tire deflects when you're riding. But a rubbing tire going in a half of a mile is pretty quick even for rubbing.

Comment: I checked out the brakes and it seems the pad does touch the tire at one particular spot on the rim. The tire seems to have gone very quickly for such a small area of contact but I will endure, adjust, and hopefully remedy based on brake pad adjustment.

Comment: If your brake touches the tyre in just one spot per revolution your wheel is out of true. Have that fixed. Adjusting the brake pads is just a cure for symptoms not for the real cause.

Comment: @csho Its 4 months later now - how did you get on? Was the brake rub the cause of the damage ?

Comment: When I went to test the brake theory, my crank arm sheared off and lodged itself a few inches into my calf. Seems like folks were probably correct in diagnosing the tire issue, the ER was certainy correct in diagnosing the impalment issue. I appreciate all the help from everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Mark and note where the split happens on the rim. It's possible that the fault on the rim is only discoverable when the tyre is inflated. Perhaps, there is a crack in the rim. If you have a pair of callipers, measure the width of the rim with the tyre inflated and uninflated. This may highlight such a crack/failure.

Also check the geometry of the wheel by slowly turning it and examining the rim at the brake block as it rotates.

If either of these tests show problems, the rim should be replaced